# Antiparticles vs. physical charges

Tags: particle-physics, antimatter

When one mentions anti-particles, a popular example given is always the opposite electric charge or the color charge. However, if I understand correctly, an anti-particle is a particle with one (or more) different value(s) of the quantum number(s) of the particle in question (Is this correct?).

If so, in the Standard Model, one counts only the different quarks based on the electric and color charge (36 of them), the charged leptons only in the electric charge (6 of them), and neutrinos in the lepton number (6 of them). But are there actually more anti-particles than that? Like are there more anti-particles of the electron-flavour for example that has other differences than the electric charge (assuming all the quantum numbers of a particle)?

Comment: No more as of now, that we know of...

Comment: For example, is a left handed electron the anti-particle of a right handed electron?

Comment: No, the left-chiral electron is the antiparticle of the right-chiral positron; so, in your counting above, you either counted all electrons, left and right,  and no positrons, or one chirality of electrons and same for positrons.

Comment: Right, I see, thank you very much! Btw one last question, can you have a quark with an anti-color? if so, doesn't that mean that a quark can exist in 6 colors, and each of these 6 can be either positively charged or negatively charged (i.e. 12 quarks). so in total we have 12x6 = 72 quarks?

Comment: No, color is like charge: you can have a red quark and its antiparticle is an attired antiquark. So, color, like charge, like fermion (baryon, lepton) number, flips under C.

Comment: Sorry what do you mean by attired antiquark? But to conclude, the concept of antired/antigreen/antiblue is only present in gluons? For example, a red positive up-quark has the blue and green positive up-quark + the negative red/green/blue up-quarks, as an antiparticle?

Comment: spell checker error: "antired" antiquark. No: a gluon is like a quark-antiquark  pair theoretically, so it has color-anticolor quantum numbers. A blue up quark has an anti-blue antiup antiquark as an antiparticle, with charge -2/3.

Comment: [Here](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Forces/color.html).

Comment: Ah, I think I understand, so what makes the "antiparticle" of a particle is the flip of all the quantum numbers at once, not one by one (right?). Thank you so much for your help once again!!

Comment: RIGHT! .........